# Parsing JSON file using sed or perl

Tags: json, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have a json file that requires parsing.
Using scripting like sed/awk or perl, how to extract value30 and substitute that to value6 prefixed by string "XX" (eg. XX + value30).
Where:

- field6 = fixed string
- value6 = fixed string
- value30 = varying string

> ```
>  [
>    {"field6" : "value6", "field30" : "value30" },
>    { "field6" : "value6", "field30" : "value30" }
>  ]
> ```

Comment: Three words; no, no, no.

Comment: Well, with a proper JSON library, Perl should be fine, actually.

Comment: Don't do it manually. Use a module like [Perl JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#decode_json)

Comment: In a nutshell: Read up on Perl JSON, do your best to solve it. Return with code examples if you get stuck. Show some effort.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fine with Perl JSON and just need help how to extract and substitute.

Comment: The whole point of a data serialization like JSON is that you **can** and **should** parse it programatically. manipulating using sed/awk is  definitely a big mistake as you never know for sure how this json struct has been written into a file, does it have many lines? all in one line? spread out? they're all the same valid json objects, but look different in a textfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this program should do what you're after:

```
use JSON qw(decode_json encode_json);
use strict;
use warnings;

# set the input line separator to undefined so the next read (<>) reads the entire file
undef $/; 
# read the entire input (stdin or a file passed on the command line) and parse it as JSON
my $data = decode_json(<>);

my $from_field = "field6";
my $to_field   = "field30";

for (@$data) {
  $_->{$to_field} = $_->{$from_field};
}

print encode_json($data), "\n";
```

It relies on the JSON module being installed, which you can install via cpanm (which should be available in most modern Perl distributions):

```
cpanm install JSON
```

If the program is in the file `substitute.pl` and your json array is in `data.json`, then you would run it as:

```
perl substitute.pl data.json
# or
cat data.json | perl substitute.pl
```

It should produce:

```
[{"field30":"value6","field6":"value6"},{"field30":"value6","field6":"value6"}]
```

Replacing `field30`'s value iwth `field6`'s.

Is this what you were attempting to do?

Comment: fyi `encode_json` and `decode_json` are preferred over `to_` and `from_` because they properly handle utf8.

Comment: also cpan plus is out of vogue (and out of the core in the most modern Perl version). The core `cpan` client will be good enough and `cpanm` (cpanminus) is now usually preferred. https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm

Comment: Thank you lot for the helpful insights, best practices, and specially Kyle's sample code. I will piece them up together.